# Timer not performing button disable function for a fixed duration

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm creating an IoT project through which I will be able to control home devices and utilities over internet. In the below code, it'll open a curtain when the switch is enabled. What I want to do here is to disable the button until the curtain is fully open which takes 5 seconds of time, so the user won't be able to press the button to close the curtain until it is fully open (because of limitations in servo motor). I've wrote the below code to accomplish this. It uses the Timer class. But it is not disabling the switch at all. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
    curtain.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new  CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {

                StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        if (response.equals("open")) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Curtain is opening..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            final long period = 5000;
                            new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    curtain.setEnabled(false);
                                }
                            }, System.currentTimeMillis(), period);
                              curtain.setEnabled(true);
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed to open", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    }

                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connection failed. Please check your internet connection.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        error.printStackTrace();

                    }
                }) {
                    @Override
                    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                        Map<String, String> getData = new HashMap<>();
                        getData.put("device", "curtain");
                        getData.put("action", "open");
                        return getData;
                    }
                };

                IotSingleton.getInstance(MainActivity.this).addToRequestQue(stringRequest);
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use `Handler` as below:

```
        ...
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

            if (response.equals("open")) {
                buttonView.setEnabled(false);
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        buttonView.setEnabled(true);
                    }
                }, 5000);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed to open", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
        ...
```

See if it works for you...!!

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It works like a charm. Could you describe what I did wrong in the above code,for the sake of learning?

Comment: @SahadNk Please read the docuemntation over here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule(java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long)